# how to retrieve recent call list and favourites list in android?

Tags: android

I need to call recent call list and favourite call list on the click of respective buttons and need the data in my own list layout.I am new to android and having lot of trouble with this.can anyone please help me..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting recent calls list,you can use CallLog in android. [Here](http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/25-android-tutorial-call-logs) is a good tutorial.[This](http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_querying_and_displaying_the_calllog-t169.html) is also helpful.

You can use it for all outgoing calls like this :

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE+"="+android.provider.CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE, null,null);
```

For all types of calls,use it like:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null,null);
```

Comment: Hello Hiral, I am using the same query to get all the types of call log but I am having one minor problem when it comes to dual sim device. My code is not working proper for dual sim devices. Can you please kindly help me in that.

Answer (score 8):

With some extra, useful code:

getFavoriteContacts:

```
Map getFavoriteContacts(){
Map contactMap = new HashMap();

Uri queryUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

String[] projection = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED};

String selection =ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED + "='1'";

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(queryUri, projection, selection,null,null);


while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String contactID = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactID));
    intent.setData(uri);
    String intentUriString = intent.toUri(0);

    String title = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

    contactMap.put(title,intentUriString);

}
cursor.close();
return contactMap;
}
```

getRecentContacts:

```
Map getRecentContacts(){
Map contactMap = new HashMap();

Uri queryUri = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;

String[] projection = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        CallLog.Calls._ID,
        CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
        CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
        CallLog.Calls.DATE};

String sortOrder = String.format("%s limit 500 ", CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");


Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(queryUri, projection, null,null,sortOrder);


while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));

    String title = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)));

    if(phoneNumber==null||title==null)continue;

    String uri = "tel:" + phoneNumber ;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    String intentUriString = intent.toUri(0);

    contactMap.put(title,intentUriString);

}
cursor.close();
return contactMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Java code to get the recent calls list:

```
Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,null);

while (phones.moveToNext()) {
    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));

    if (phoneNumber.length() > 6) {
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));

        numbers.add(phoneNumber);

    }
}
```