# How do I discover whether the recent call was missed?

Tags: android

I am developing an app that sends an SMS when there is a missed call.
If someone calls, and the receiver is not able to receive the call, the call will become a missed call (unanswered) so the app will send an SMS to the caller.

How do I to find out whether the recent call was a missed (unanswered) call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) to listen for call state change from `CALL_STATE_RINGING` to `CALL_STATE_IDLE` which indicates the phone was not picked up.

example on how to check your call log from this link

http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_querying_and_displaying_the_calllog-t169.html

Answer (score 0):

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7995442/1629707), and you can use `android.provider.CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE` to specify the call type.